# ActionBar (using ActionbarSherlock) inside a PreferenceActivity on Gingerbread

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, preferenceactivity

I have an Android app where I've set the min SDK version to be 9 (Gingerbread).  I have a preference activity where I would like to show an actionbar which works just fine on ICS+ devices but does not show up on devices running GB.

Upon further [investigation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/SE9y4kbZRPw), I found that ABS is not supported when used with `PreferenceActivity`.

Is there *any* workaround for this? I simply need to show an actionbar (with some options items) on devices running Gingerbread.

Comment: If you used ActionBarCompat of v7, try this https://gist.github.com/0e9fe2119b901921b160

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SherlockPreferenceActivity.